# MongoDB embedded docs referencing other embedded docs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm just learning mongodb, and am seeking document design advice.  Within the same document, I want embedded references to reference other embedded references.

Imagine I have a collection "Profiles", which starts with a list of thingsILike.  At some point later, some calculation logic looks at the thingsILike to draw (and save) conclusions.  The conclusions should reference items in the original list...

```
var myProfile = {
  "thingsILike": [
    {"type": "movie", "name": "300"},
    {"type": "movie", "name": "gladiator"},
    {"type": "tvshow", "name": "spartacus"}
  ],
  "conclusions": [
    {"ancientGore": [SOMEHOW REFERENCE: 300, gladiator, spartacus]},
    {"gladiators": [SOMEHOW REFERENCE: gladiator, spartacus]}
  ]
}
```

Assuming I have valid reasons for a single collection with the 2 lists, what is the best way to reference the original thingILike in the conclusion entry?

I would like to have the conclusion keep a list of ObjectID's of the thingsILike (requires objectIds for the thingsILike even though they are not collections).  It would be nice if mongo (or mongoose) populated those references like they would for collection references.

So, is there some known elegant pattern or support for this I have not found yet?  Or do I just need to use brute force here and handle the references through code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be worthwhile to reevaluate if using subdocument arrays for this is a good design choice. From a MongoLab [post on subdocument arrays](http://blog.mongolab.com/2013/04/thinking-about-arrays-in-mongodb/): "However, one must be *careful*. Data models that call for very large arrays, or **arrays with high rates of modification**, can often lead to performance problems." This might not be an issue with your design but it is worth revisiting.

Moving on to the question at hand, MongoDB does not provide a method for document properties to internally reference other properties. Mongoose can in the form of [virtuals](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html), but I don't believe this would solve your question directly.

In regards to populating the values in `conclusions`, assuming "the calculation at a latter time" would likely provide an array of ObjectIds for each conclusion, you would need to postprocess the returned document to populate the values. This could be done with virtuals as well or by a method on the mongoose model.

An approach using a virtual getter could solve this partially but would require that `thingsILike` tag items with conclusion keys. This updating could be done with a virtual setter or directly via "the calculation at a latter time".

Using this approach the actual object in mongodb would look something like:

```
{
  "thingsILike": [
    {"type": "movie", "name": "300", conclusions: ["ancientGore"]},
    {"type": "movie", "name": "gladiator", conclusions: ["ancientGore", "gladiators"]},
    {"type": "tvshow", "name": "spartacus", conclusions: ["ancientGore", "gladiators"]}
  ]
}
```

And the virtual path for `conclusions` would be:

```
MyProfileSchema.virtual('conclusions').get(function () {
  // `this` is the parent document
  // Iterate over things and create conclusions
  return this.thingsILike.reduce(function createConclusions(conclusions, thing) {
    if (Array.isArray(thing.conclusions)) {
      thing.conclusions.forEach(function assignConclusion(conclusion) {
        if (conclusions[conclusion] === undefined) {
          conclusions[conclusion] = [];
        }

        conclusions[conclusion].push(thing);
      });
    }

    return conclusions;
  }, {});
});
```

Note that this is an example of how you could use a virtual getter and that various optimizations can be made to it. For example, caching the object and only rebuilding the object if `thingsILike` is updated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I will look into virtual methods more deeply.  I have indeed considered the long-array performance concerns.  My lists are smaller than my example implies.  I am leaning towards keeping the reference list on the Conclusions instead of on the ThingsILike with the objective of not altering the raw data for sake of the calculated results.    Thanks again for helping me navigate through this new world ;).